# Creating a convolutional layer with weight normalization?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, gradient-descent, mathematics

This paper proposes parameterizing convolutional weights by having the primary weights normalized to unit norm plus an extra scalar weight: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07868.pdf Implementations do exist, but they seem kind of limited and finnicky with Keras versions and optimizers.

Would it be fundamentally different mathematically when doing gradient descent during training with backpropagation if I implemented this with 3 layers instead?

1. The 1st layer(s) would be branching convolutional layers with a unit norm kernel constraint (which is officially supported in Keras) and no bias weights. This way the input channels wouldn't be summed over.
2. The 2nd layer would be a merging layer that would concatenate along the input channel dimension we conveniently left untouched.
3. The 3rd layer would be another convolutional layer this time with a 1x1 convolution plus bias weights to perform the weighted summation with bias that would have followed the filtering done in a normal convolutional layer.